# What are the top candidate ideas for pursuing a good life?

Tags: ethics

What are the candidate pursuits for a good life and who are the best to read to get a good understanding of the argument for pursuing any one over others? So far, these come to mind:

- Self-expression and creative efforts (e.g. art, writing, invention)
- Purpose/meaningfulness (Stoics? Existentialists?)
- Helping others (Utilitarians? Humanists?)
- Relationships (Harvard Study of Adult Development?)
- Optimal experience (e.g. Flow by Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi?)
- Pleasure (Epicurus?)
- Virtue (Ancient Greeks?)
- Personal growth (skills, knowledge, wisdom, etc)
- Productive work (Ayn Rand?)
- Serving God (Calvin?)

What an I missing in this list? What terms am I not using that could be good in answering these questions?

I hope you'll consider it answerable, as I'd like to get a list of concepts here and make sure I haven't missed any "canonical" candidates.

Pursuing any of these may involve value judgments in deciding how to do so, but to me, answering that question strikes me as easier than deciding which of the above items to focus on. Of course, most would agree that one should pursue all of these things, but ordering/ranking them might be helpful, even just for discussion.  So what's missing from the list above?

Comment: • Delete your social media accounts. • Learn to think for yourself. • If "everyone" agrees, they're probably wrong.

Comment: Look at [SEP Well-Being](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/well-being/), and [Happiness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/happiness/).

Comment: Consciously minimizing wasted time.

Comment: You may wish to include Spinoza's "Ethics" and Theological Political Treatise TTP. The 'caption' might read: Pursuing natural intelligence to attain a useful existence. CMS

Comment: User4894 and Cristian, those may be good life lessons, but they aren't really the broad categories of pursuits that I am looking for.

Comment: Charles, thanks for that, I will read a bit more on Spinoza.  At first blush, it seems like it fits under "Personal growth", but I will look further.